# Combining queries into one and then ordering by date

Tags: python, django

I have 3 tables. User, Post, and Share. Post is a table that contains all posts. Post has a one to many relationship with Share. That being said, the Share table is a table where it indicates which posts a user has shared. Here's the structure of the tables:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    share_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Share(models.Model):
    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shared_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I want specifically is a query that gets what posts the user has shared and the posts the user has created. For example, let's say we have the same data:

**Post table**

```
id    user    status    share_count    created_at    url
1      1       hello         32         2017-06-01   hello
2      2       What's up     22         2017-07-01   whats-up
```

**Share table**

```
post    user   shared_at
2       2      2017-07-02
```

I want a query that will get a user's shared posts + their posts. So let's say I want to do that for user 1. The result should be post 1 and post 2 since the user posted post 1 and also shared post 2 from user 2. Here's what I have so far:
from itertools import chain

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1) # pick a user

own_posts = user.post_set.order_by('-created_at')
shared_posts = user.share_set.order_by('-shared_at')

combined = itertools.chain(own_posts, shared_posts)

def get_ts(obj):
   try:
     return obj.created_at
   except AttributeError:
     return obj.shared_at

last_5 = sorted(combined, key=get_ts, reverse=True)[:5]
```

I get this error after I do the last line:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and
>   'NoneType'

How can I make this work? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It does not make much sense to me since you are combinint `Post`s with `Share`s typically you want a collection of elements of the *same* type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make it quite complex. The core problem is here that your collection contains *two* types of elements `Post`s and `share`s. I really advice you *not* to do this, since it will only make it harder to process it.

We can however construct for example a queryset that will return posts that are either posted by the user, or shared by that user. For example with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Post.objects.filter(
    Q(user=some_user) | 
    Q(share__user=some_user)
).annotate(
    shared_or_created=Coalesce('share__shared_at', 'created_at')
).order_by('-shared_or_created')
```

So now we have a list of posts that are either created by `some_user`, or shared by `some_user`. Next we annotate each post with a `shared_or_created` field that either contains the time when it was shared, or in case it was not shared (so created by the user), the time when it was created. Finally we sort on that attribute in descending order.

The advantage of encoding this into a query, is that it is processed at the database level. Furthermore it is still a queryset, so you can add extra filters, slicing, etc. on it.

Comment: When I do the `annotate` line, I get an error that says:  `File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 94, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Looks to me this is not related, it has problems parsing a timestamp. But hard to tell since you fail to post the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This does work it was my fault. When you say "I really advice you not to do this" since my collection contains two types of elements, how do you advise I do this? Are you talking about the way I distribute my tables? Or are you talking about the original query I was making in my question?

Comment: Well typically one better avoids collections of different types, so I would construct (like here) a queryset of `Post`s. Optionally you can annotate it to see if it was a constructed or liked post (although the check is easy in Python as well).

Comment: I see, now when you say "The advantage of encoding this into a query is that it is processed at the database level" does that mean it does not get processed until we do some sort of evaluation to it? In other words, it's lazy evaluated?

Comment: @user2896120: exactly. Although of course by for example using `list(..)` you can force evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in the final line you are trying to sort based on the key `get_ts`, but (at least) two elements of `combined` have `None` as their value for `get_ts`, and so cannot be compared.

Comment: So is there a fix for this?

Comment: @user2896120 you need to check that `get_ts` is correctly getting the time stamps. If it is, then the issue is that some timestamps (i.e. `created_at` or `shared_at`) have a value of `None`. This seems like an undesired value, and so you should check how these entries were created to see how this is happening.